# JOptionPane Array Elements

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

I have been trying to work this out for the passed couple of days while trying to learn java. I have been teaching myself how to use option panes to display messages and I have recently tried to make use of the buttons but I am having no luck getting further in the code when I try and pass through the array Elements. Here is my code so far; I have managed to create the `JOptionPane` and I have told it what to do when a button has been pressed but as I run the code, it does nothing. Can anyone help me?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Tinker01
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AdultTicket adultTicket = new AdultTicket();
        ChildTicket childTicket = new ChildTicket();
        OverFiftyTicket overFiftyTicket = new OverFiftyTicket();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        String[] options =
            {"Adult Ticket" , "Childs Ticket" , "Over Fifty Ticket" };
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "What ticket would you like to buy? " + " ", " ",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);

        if (options.equals(options[0]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + adultTicket.getAdultTicket());
        }
        else if (options.equals(options[1]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + childTicket.getChildTicket());
        }
        else if (options.equals(options[2]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + overFiftyTicket.getOverFiftyTicket());
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: array passed to JOptionPane creates JComboBox, more in Oracle tutorial

Comment: Read your code carefully: `options.equals(options[0])` What does this do? Will it ever evaluate to `true`?

Comment: You also might want to make a note of the return value from JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Comment: Hi BackSlash, options.equals(options[0]) should point the if statement to the correct option, but I am a beginner in Java and don't have much knowledge of this. I am now looking into the JComboBox to try get the program to move to the next stage.

Answer (score 2):

Take some time to go over [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input). You're expecting input, and that's what you want to check against, so you should be using one of the `showInputDialogs`. See [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input), you'll see that you can pass the `String[]` to the static method, and it will render as a combobox of options, and also return the exact string for which you can check against. Something like

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InputPaneDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] possibilities = {"Adult Ticket" , "Childs Ticket" , "Over Fifty Ticket" };
        String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                            null,
                            "What ticket would you like to buy?",
                            "Ticket Dialog",
                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                            null,
                            possibilities,
                            possibilities[0]);
        switch(s) {
            case "Adult Ticket" : System.out.println("Buy Adult"); break;
            case  "Childs Ticket"  : System.out.println("Child Adult"); break;
            case "Over Fifty Ticket" : System.out.println("Over Fifty Adult"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Contextually, this seems like the more proper approach, as the option dialog is more for yes/no type input.

Answer (score 1):

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog will return an int representing your selected option. You can rewrite your code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AdultTicket adultTicket = new AdultTicket();
    ChildTicket childTicket = new ChildTicket();
    OverFiftyTicket overFiftyTicket = new OverFiftyTicket();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    String[] options =
        {"Adult Ticket" , "Childs Ticket" , "Over Fifty Ticket" };
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "What ticket would you like to buy? " + " ", " ",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);

    switch(option) {
        case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + adultTicket.getAdultTicket() );
                break;
        case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + childTicket.getChildTicket());
                break;
        case 2: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + overFiftyTicket.getOverFiftyTicket());
                break;
        default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "No ticket selected");        
    }

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, as *BackSlash* already said in his comment, `options.equals(options[0])` will ever return false. What you want to acchieve is:

```
String[] options = {"Adult Ticket" , "Childs Ticket" , "Over Fifty Ticket" };
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
        "What ticket would you like to buy?", " ",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[2]);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + adultTicket.getAdultTicket());
}
else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + childTicket.getChildTicket());
}
else if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your ticket price is £" + overFiftyTicket.getOverFiftyTicket());
}
```

Note that none if the if-statements must be true. If the user exited the dialog without clicking one of the buttons, `result` will be `JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION`.

For more information on `JOptionPane`, read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) of it.